# Linking AVR programs with Cargo

Tags: linker, rust, avr, rust-cargo

I have a Rust project which I am currently compiling and linking by hand:

```
rustc --target=avr-atmel-none src/main.rs  --emit=obj -o _build/main.rs.o -C opt-level=3
avr-gcc -Os -Wl,--gc-sections -mmcu=atmega328p -o _build/image.elf _build/main.rs.o 
avr-objcopy -Oihex -R.eeprom _build/image.elf _build/image.hex
```

I would like to automate this with Cargo, so I started by setting `avr-gcc` as the linker, by adding the following to `.cargo/config`:

```
[build]
target = "avr-atmel-none"

[target.avr-atmel-none]
linker = "avr-gcc"
```

However, it seems `cargo` passes some extra arguments to the linker that `avr-gcc` cannot handle:

```
11:47:10 [cactus@galaxy interrupt-bug]$ cargo build --release
   Compiling hello-avr v0.1.0 (file:///home/cactus/prog/rust/avr/interrupt-bug)
error: linking with `avr-gcc` failed: exit code: 1
  |
  = note: "avr-gcc" "-Wl,--as-needed" "-L" "/home/cactus/prog/rust/rust-avr/build/build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/stage1/lib/rustlib/avr-atmel-none/lib" "/home/cactus/prog/rust/avr/interrupt-bug/target/avr-atmel-none/release/deps/hello_avr-8bce8eb24807f5a8.0.o" "-o" "/home/cactus/prog/rust/avr/interrupt-bug/target/avr-atmel-none/release/deps/hello_avr-8bce8eb24807f5a8" "-Wl,--gc-sections" "-pie" "-Wl,-O1" "-nodefaultlibs" "-L" "/home/cactus/prog/rust/avr/interrupt-bug/target/avr-atmel-none/release/deps" "-L" "/home/cactus/prog/rust/avr/interrupt-bug/target/release/deps" "-L" "/home/cactus/prog/rust/rust-avr/build/build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/stage1/lib/rustlib/avr-atmel-none/lib"
  = note: /usr/lib/gcc/avr/4.8.2/../../../avr/bin/ld: -pie not supported
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How do I remove these extra arguments from the `avr-gcc` invocation? Moreover, is there a way to integrate the third step, i.e. the `avr-objcopy` call, into the Cargo workflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A word of warning: development on [avr-rust](https://github.com/avr-rust/rust) can politely be said to be *cutting edge*. It's very likely something that works one day may not the next, so answers like this are likely to go out of date quickly. We welcome all contributors to the project to help make it more usable.

---

You need to specify a target JSON file and the full set of linker arguments. Here's an example from an older project of mine (some of the exact values may now be incorrect):

```
{
  "llvm-target": "avr-atmel-none",
  "target-endian": "little",
  "target-pointer-width": "16",
  "os": "none",
  "target-env": "gnu",
  "target-vendor": "unknown",
  "arch": "avr",
  "data-layout": "e-p:16:16:16-i8:8:8-i16:16:16-i32:32:32-i64:64:64-f32:32:32-f64:64:64-n8",

  "executables": true,

  "linker": "avr-gcc",
  "linker-flavor": "gcc",
  "pre-link-args": {
    "gcc": ["-mmcu=atmega328p", "-nostartfiles", "../interrupt_vector.S"]
  },
  "exe-suffix": ".elf",
  "post-link-args": {
    "gcc": ["-Wl,--no-gc-sections"]
  },

  "no-compiler-rt": true
}
```

For a full example see [my example repository](https://github.com/shepmaster/rust-arduino-blink-led-no-core-with-cargo). This project used to work (see my [blog series](http://jakegoulding.com/blog/2016/05/27/rust-on-an-arduino-uno-part-6/)). I have recently updated it so it compiles against the master branch of avr-rust, but haven't tested the compiled code on a real device.

---

There's an open RFC for having [Cargo post build scripts](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1777), but it doesn't seem likely to be merged. I continue to use a Makefile. [xargo](https://github.com/japaric/xargo) might be an alternative. There were also rumbles about a cargo subcommand that could be created.

Comment: With your `.json` file (removing the `interrupt_vector.S` dependency that I don't need), `cargo build` finishes without error, but the resulting `.elf` file is only 701 bytes, compared to a hand-linked `.elf` which is 4002 bytes. `avr-objdump -S` shows the short `.elf` file not to contain any code.

Comment: @Cactus please check again. The compiler always adds `-Wl,--gc-sections`, which removes everything. `post-link-args` is supposed to undo that, but the structure of it was wrong before, and I've now changed it.