# Cargo creates empty ELF file

Tags: linker, rust, rust-cargo

I'm trying to use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43702805/477476) by writing a custom target `.json` file with `"linker-flavor":"gcc"`. My full target `.json` file is:

```
{
  "llvm-target": "avr-atmel-none",
  "cpu": "atmega328p",
  "target-endian": "little",
  "target-pointer-width": "16",
  "os": "none",
  "target-env": "gnu",
  "target-vendor": "unknown",
  "arch": "avr",
  "data-layout": "e-p:16:16:16-i8:8:8-i16:16:16-i32:32:32-i64:64:64-f32:32:32-f64:64:64-n8",

  "executables": true,

  "linker": "avr-gcc",
  "linker-flavor": "gcc",
  "pre-link-args": {
    "gcc": ["-Os -mmcu=atmega328p"]
  },
  "exe-suffix": ".elf",
  "post-link-args": {
    "gcc": ["-Wl,--gc-sections"]
  },

  "no-default-libraries": false
}
```

Running `cargo build` with this finishes without any error messages:

```
$ cargo build --release -v
   Compiling core v0.1.0 (https://github.com/gergoerdi/rust-avr-libcore-mini?rev=adda44aa91ac517aab6915447592ee4cad26564c#adda44aa)
     Running `rustc --crate-name core /home/cactus/.cargo/git/checkouts/rust-avr-libcore-mini-37e279d93a70b45a/adda44a/src/lib.rs --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,link -C opt-level=3 -C metadata=655bb622dd229da9 -C extra-filename=-655bb622dd229da9 --out-dir /home/cactus/prog/rust/avr/chip8-avr/target/avr-atmega328p/release/deps --target avr-atmega328p -L dependency=/home/cactus/prog/rust/avr/chip8-avr/target/avr-atmega328p/release/deps -L dependency=/home/cactus/prog/rust/avr/chip8-avr/target/release/deps --cap-lints allow`
   Compiling chip8-engine v0.1.0 (https://github.com/gergoerdi/rust-avr-chip8-engine?rev=c6f88737bae4dae0bd6c5c2bbc73737e6dfadfcd#c6f88737)
     Running `rustc --crate-name chip8_engine /home/cactus/.cargo/git/checkouts/rust-avr-chip8-engine-4bce60f3f178d33a/c6f8873/src/lib.rs --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,link -C opt-level=3 -C metadata=2197ff1f15f697c9 -C extra-filename=-2197ff1f15f697c9 --out-dir /home/cactus/prog/rust/avr/chip8-avr/target/avr-atmega328p/release/deps --target avr-atmega328p -L dependency=/home/cactus/prog/rust/avr/chip8-avr/target/avr-atmega328p/release/deps -L dependency=/home/cactus/prog/rust/avr/chip8-avr/target/release/deps --extern core=/home/cactus/prog/rust/avr/chip8-avr/target/avr-atmega328p/release/deps/libcore-655bb622dd229da9.rlib --cap-lints allow`
   Compiling chip8-avr v0.1.0 (file:///home/cactus/prog/rust/avr/chip8-avr)
     Running `rustc --crate-name chip8_avr src/main.rs --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C opt-level=3 -C metadata=014a8fed19cbc611 -C extra-filename=-014a8fed19cbc611 --out-dir /home/cactus/prog/rust/avr/chip8-avr/target/avr-atmega328p/release/deps --target avr-atmega328p -L dependency=/home/cactus/prog/rust/avr/chip8-avr/target/avr-atmega328p/release/deps -L dependency=/home/cactus/prog/rust/avr/chip8-avr/target/release/deps --extern chip8_engine=/home/cactus/prog/rust/avr/chip8-avr/target/avr-atmega328p/release/deps/libchip8_engine-2197ff1f15f697c9.rlib --extern core=/home/cactus/prog/rust/avr/chip8-avr/target/avr-atmega328p/release/deps/libcore-655bb622dd229da9.rlib`
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 15.99 secs
```

However, the resulting ELF file's `.text` section is empty:

```
$ avr-objdump -h target/avr-atmega328p/release/chip8-avr.elf 

target/avr-atmega328p/release/chip8-avr.elf:     file format elf32-avr

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA       LMA       File off  Algn
  0 .text         00000000  00000000  00000000  00000074  2**1
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
  1 .data         00000000  00800060  00000000  00000074  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
  2 .stab         0000012c  00000000  00000000  00000074  2**2
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
  3 .stabstr      0000005d  00000000  00000000  000001a0  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
  4 .comment      00000011  00000000  00000000  000001fd  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY
```

So to figure out what's going on, I thought I'd replace my `avr-gcc`
with a small shellscript that logs its arguments before passing it to
the real `avr-gcc` executable.

This shows me that `rustc`/`cargo` is trying to run the following
command line to do the linking:

```
/usr/bin/avr-gcc -Os -mmcu=atmega328p \
  -L /home/cactus/prog/rust/rust-avr/build/build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/stage1/lib/rustlib/avr-atmega328p/lib \
  /home/cactus/prog/rust/avr/chip8-avr/target/avr-atmega328p/release/deps/chip8_avr-014a8fed19cbc611.0.o \
  -o /home/cactus/prog/rust/avr/chip8-avr/target/avr-atmega328p/release/deps/chip8_avr-014a8fed19cbc611.elf \
  -Wl,--gc-sections \
  -L /home/cactus/prog/rust/avr/chip8-avr/target/avr-atmega328p/release/deps -L /home/cactus/prog/rust/avr/chip8-avr/target/release/deps -L /home/cactus/prog/rust/rust-avr/build/build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/stage1/lib/rustlib/avr-atmega328p/lib \
  -Wl,-Bstatic /home/cactus/prog/rust/avr/chip8-avr/target/avr-atmega328p/release/deps/libchip8_engine-2197ff1f15f697c9.rlib \
  /home/cactus/prog/rust/avr/chip8-avr/target/avr-atmega328p/release/deps/libcore-655bb622dd229da9.rlib \
  -Wl,-Bdynamic -Wl,--gc-sections
```

If I run the exact same command manually, with the exact same environment variables, I get a good ELF file with
the right contents (note that its `.text` section is not empty):

```
$ /usr/bin/avr-gcc -Os -mmcu=atmega328p -L /home/cactus/prog/rust/rust-avr/build/build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/stage1/lib/rustlib/avr-atmega328p/lib /home/cactus/prog/rust/avr/chip8-avr/target/avr-atmega328p/release/deps/chip8_avr-014a8fed19cbc611.0.o -o /home/cactus/prog/rust/avr/chip8-avr/target/avr-atmega328p/release/deps/chip8_avr-014a8fed19cbc611.elf -Wl,--gc-sections -L /home/cactus/prog/rust/avr/chip8-avr/target/avr-atmega328p/release/deps -L /home/cactus/prog/rust/avr/chip8-avr/target/release/deps -L /home/cactus/prog/rust/rust-avr/build/build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/stage1/lib/rustlib/avr-atmega328p/lib -Wl,-Bstatic /home/cactus/prog/rust/avr/chip8-avr/target/avr-atmega328p/release/deps/libchip8_engine-2197ff1f15f697c9.rlib /home/cactus/prog/rust/avr/chip8-avr/target/avr-atmega328p/release/deps/libcore-655bb622dd229da9.rlib -Wl,-Bdynamic -Wl,--gc-sections
$ avr-objdump -h target/avr-atmega328p/release/deps/chip8_avr-014a8fed19cbc611.elf  
target/avr-atmega328p/release/deps/chip8_avr-014a8fed19cbc611.elf:     file format elf32-avr

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA       LMA       File off  Algn
  0 .data         0000020e  00800100  00001a56  00001af0  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
  1 .text         00001a56  00000000  00000000  00000094  2**1
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
  2 .bss          000001fa  0080030e  0080030e  00001cfe  2**0
                  ALLOC
  3 .stab         000007ec  00000000  00000000  00001d00  2**2
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
  4 .stabstr      000000b0  00000000  00000000  000024ec  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
  5 .comment      00000011  00000000  00000000  0000259c  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY
```

So why does `cargo` silently produce a nonsensical empty ELF file, if
running the (supposedly) same command from the shell results in a valid ELF file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by a bug in the target `.json` file; specifically, this part:

```
"pre-link-args": {
  "gcc": ["-Os -mmcu=atmega328p"]
},
```

The arguments are passed directly as `argv` to the linker, so multiple arguments need to be split into multiple elements of the array here:

```
"pre-link-args": {
  "gcc": ["-Os", "-mmcu=atmega328p"]
},
```

The reason this problem didn't show up when using the special logging version of `avr-gcc` is that the log only contained all the arguments together, so there was no difference between the two representations.

As for `avr-gcc '-Os -mmcu=atmega328p'` creating an empty `.elf` file, it seems that is simply a side-effect of not specifying any (valid) `-mmcu` argument.